# How do I determine which text in a corpus contains an error generated by the NLTK suite in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, nltk, corpus

I am trying to do some rudimentary corpus analysis with Python. I am getting the following error message(s):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#28>", line 2, in <module>
      print(len(poems.words(f)), f)
      File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 240, in __len__
      for tok in self.iterate_from(self._toknum[-1]):
      File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 306, in iterate_from
      tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
      File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py", line 134, in _read_word_block
      words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))
      File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1220, in readline
      new_chars = self._read(readsize)
      File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1458, in _read
      chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)
      File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1489, in _incr_decode
      return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')
      File "C:\Python38-32\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
      return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 12: invalid start byte
```

My assumption is that there is a UTF error in one of the 202 text files I am looking at.
Is there any way of telling, from the error messages, which file or files have the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the files ids (the paths of your corpus files) you can open all of them with `encoding="utf-8"`

If you don't know the paths, assuming that you are using the nltk corpus loader, you can get them by using:

```
poems.fileids()
```

After that, for every file in your list of files (for example `fileids`) you can try:

```
for file_ in fileids:
    try:
        with open(file_, encoding="utf-8") a f_i:
            f_i.readlines()
    except:
        print("You got problems with the file: ", file_)
```

Anyway, your loader has also a parameter named "encoding" that you can use for the correct encoding of your corpus. By default is set to "utf-8"

More details here: [nltk corpus loader](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/api.html)